# ASP.NET　CURL　バイナリデータを複数アップロード

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl

ASP.NET MVC C#
apiControllerを継承して、WebAPIを作成しています。

以前開発時は、1種類のバイナリデータをリクエストのボディに含めてPOSTしておりました。
curl --data-binary @"ファイル名"
controller post(byte[] data)

2種類のバイナリデータ（pemファイルとdatファイル）をPOSTしたいです。
curlとControllerはどのように実装したらよろしいでしょうか。
（RESTAPIとして使用）

Comment: これらの記事が参考になるかも。[Multiple File Upload in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36210413/9014308), [MVC Multiple File Upload:...](https://sensibledev.com/mvc-multiple-file-upload/), [Uploading Multiple Files...](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-multiple-files-in-asp-net-mvc/), [Uploading multiple files...](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/287/uploading-multiple-files-with-asp-net-mvc), [Upload files with CURL](https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76), [POST multiple files...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49101319/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

> 2種類のバイナリデータ（pemファイルとdatファイル）をPOSTしたいです。
> curlとControllerはどのように実装したらよろしいでしょうか。

以前自分の Windows 10 の開発マシンに作った ASP.NET MVC5 アプリの試験用コードを使って試してみました。

**まずは curl 側:**

Windows 10 搭載の curl ですが、以下のコマンド（-x 127.0.0.1:8888 は Fiddler で要求・応答をキャプチャするため追加、-k は SSL 検証を無効にするため追加したものです）で、

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:8888 -k -F "postedfiles=@image1.jpg" -F "postedfiles=@image2.jpg" https://localhost:44365/File/MultipleUpload
```

以下の要求が送信されます。

```
POST https://localhost:44365/File/MultipleUpload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44365
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 112670
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------12dea397e7140308

--------------------------12dea397e7140308
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="postedfiles"; filename="image1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

・・・ファイルの中身（省略）・・・
--------------------------12dea397e7140308
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="postedfiles"; filename="image2.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

・・・ファイルの中身（省略）・・・
--------------------------12dea397e7140308--
```

**そして、ASP.NET MVC アプリ側:**

Web サーバーが上の要求を受け取ると、MVC アプリは curl コマンドの URL に指定されたコントローラー/アクションメソッド（上の例では　File/MultipleUpload）の `IList<HttpPostedFileBase>` 型の引数 postedfiles に送信されてきたファイルをモデルバインドします。以下の画像を見てください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考に検証に使ったサンプルコードを以下にアップしておきます。今回のスレッドの話とは関係ないものも入ってますが、そのあたりの見分けはつきますよね？　curl では AntiForgeryToken は送れないので [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] をコメントアウトしているところに注意してください。

**Model**

```
public class MultipleUploadModels
{
    public string CustomField { get; set; }
    public IList<HttpPostedFileBase> PostedFiles { get; set; }
}
```

**Action Method**

```
public ActionResult MultipleUpload()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MultipleUpload(MultipleUploadModels model)
{
    string result = "";
    string customFiled = model.CustomField;
    IList<HttpPostedFileBase> postedFiles = model.PostedFiles;

    // input type="file" でファイルが選択されてない場合でも postedFiles は null にならないし、
    // postedFiles.Count は 0 にならない（1 になる）。従い、以下のコードでは制御が else に飛ぶことはない
    if (postedFiles != null && postedFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase postedFile in postedFiles)
        {
            if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // アップロードされたファイル名を取得。ブラウザが IE の
                // 場合 postedFile.FileName はクライアント側でのフル
                // パスになることがあるので Path.GetFileName を使う
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

                // 保存ホルダの物理パス\ファイル名
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles") + "\\" + filename;

                // アップロードされたファイルを保存
                postedFile.SaveAs(path);

                result += filename + " (" + postedFile.ContentType + ") - " +
                                  postedFile.ContentLength.ToString() +
                                  " bytes アップロード完了<br />";
            }                    
        }
        result += "送信された CustomField: " + customFiled;
    }
    else
    {
        result = "ファイルアップロードに失敗しました";
    }

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Content(result);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Result = result;
        return View();
    }
}
```